# Got building snapshots error when deploy with Nodejitsu

Tags: node.js, deployment, nodejitsu

I creat a simple Node.js app and deploy it by command "jitsu deploy" and got that error.

> `info:    Creating snapshot 0.0.1-1
> info:    Uploading: [=============================] 100%
> error:   Error running command deploy
> error:   Error building snapshot
> error:   Nodejitsu Error (500): Internal Server Error`

I don't know what to do with this, this's first time I try to use Nodejitsu
Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set node version as follows in you package.json file:

"node": "0.10.x"

OR

"node": "0.8.x"

Make sure you have .x at the end, it will not work if you set specific version, such as 0.10.29

Comment: Thanks, it helped! The error could have been more verbose though